# How to convert JSON column values into separated schema with many rows in SQL Server?

Tags: json, sql-server

I have a data set that has only one column has `JSON` format. Here is snap from the table:
[image]

Here are only Genres column in JSON that I want to create another table to have many rows for each row in this table to list the genre id and name and connect the two table by the primary key

I have used `OPENJSON` available in `SQL Server` but all what I get only for one record and not for the whole table

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(MAX) = (SELECT TOP (1) [Genres]
  FROM [IMDB_movies].[dbo].[Genre_movies])

 SELECT * 
 FROM OPENJSON(@json)
 WITH (id FLOAT,
 name VARCHAR(100))
```

But I have no idea how to convert the whole Genres records in the table  into new table of many rows for each tag in Genres record in the main table.

Comment: Are you sure, it has only Id and Name columns in all the JSON values?

Answer (score 0):

Try this answer:

```
DECLARE @Genre_movies TABLE(Generes VARCHAR(8000))
INSERT INTO @Genre_movies VALUES('[{"id":"28","name":"Action"},{"id":"12","name":"Adventure"}]')
INSERT INTO @Genre_movies VALUES('[{"id":"16","name":"Animation"},{"id":"14","name":"Fantasy"}]')

DECLARE @Result TABLE(ID INT,Name VARCHAR(20))

SELECT Generes,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) RN
INTO #Temp
FROM @Genre_movies

DECLARE @MIN INT,@MAX INT,@JSONValue VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @MAX=MAX(RN),@MIN=MIN(RN) FROM #Temp

WHILE(@MAX>=@MIN)
BEGIN
    SELECT @JSONValue=Generes FROM #Temp WHERE RN=@MIN

    INSERT INTO @Result
    SELECT * 
     FROM OPENJSON(@JSONValue)
     WITH (id FLOAT,
     name VARCHAR(100))

    SET @MIN=@MIN+1
END

SELECT * FROM @Result
DROP TABLE #Temp
```